# Keep Cisco site-to-site tunnel up permanently

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, ipsec, site-to-site

I have Cisco ASA site-to-site tunnel with remote and which i don't have control.

I have following config:

```
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 28800
```

Crypto map

```
crypto map VPN 10 match address ACL-VPN
crypto map VPN 10 set pfs
crypto map VPN 10 set peer 201.222.X.X
crypto map VPN 10 set ikev1 transform-set VPN-ESP-AES-SHA
crypto map VPN 10 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
crypto map VPN interface outside
```

Tunnel group

```
tunnel-group 201.222.X.X type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 201.222.X.X ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
 isakmp keepalive threshold 10 retry 10
```

One option i have SLA icmp to generate traffic and keep it up but what other option i have to make it up if i don't want to use `SLA` feature?

If i change isakmp lifetime to `zero` does that required change to remote end?

## EDIT - 1

[image]

- If i ping from PC-1 to any ip in 10.10.10.x range (no matter its up or down) my vpn tunnel get trigger and up
- If i ping from ASA-Local to ip in 10.10.10.x range, vpn tunnel not getting up because its using `outside` interface default to ping.
- If i ping from ASA-Local using this command `ping inside 10.10.10.1` my tunnel get trigger and working.

Comment: Your options are: 1. The IP SLA; 2. Always be sending something over the tunnel from host/server to host/server to keep the tunnel up (effectively just another form of an IP SLA); 3. Configure the lifetimes on BOTH sides (changing only one side will cause other issues).

Comment: You should convert that into an answer, @JesseP.

Comment: @TeunVink I didn't really feel like it was answering the problem as much as just confirming what the OP already knew, but I added it anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep an ASA tunnel up for lifetime?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47717/how-to-keep-an-asa-tunnel-up-for-lifetime)

Comment: Sorry for slightly not answering the question, but what is the use case for this? The idea behind using IKEv1 is to generate key material for the Child (IPsec) SA so trying to keep the tunnel up forever (no rekey) slightly defeats the point. IKE rekeys the child SA prior to lifetime expiry such that there is no traffic loss as the two SA's are temporarily installed together If you want a tunnel not to rekey you can set the ipsec lifetime for both timer and data to disabled (and will stay up until other end rekeys), or you can create an IPsec child SA with no IKE session by creating an IPsec tu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options are:

1. The IP SLA
2. Always be sending something over the tunnel from host/server to host/server to keep the tunnel up (effectively just another form of an IP SLA)
3. Configure the lifetimes on BOTH sides (changing only one side will cause other issues).

Edit (in response to how to apply the group-policy):

```
tunnel-group 74.201.x.x general-attributes
 default-group-policy FOO
```

Edit 2 (in response to SLA source-interface):

```
sla monitor <number>
 type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho <target> interface <source interface>
```

Comment: i was reading about `vpn-idle-timeout none` not sure about that if it support site-to-site

Comment: @Satish I use that setting on one of my tunnels without any issue.  What are you seeing that's causing doubt?

Comment: where i should apply that setting?

Comment: @Satish You apply it as part of the group-policy that your tunnel is set to use. `group-policy <tunnel policy name> attributes` and then `vpn-idle-timeout none`. Then make sure your tunnel-group is set to use whatever policy you add that command to.

Comment: I am confused, This is what i did `group-policy FOO attributes` and inside policy i set `vpn-idle-timeout none` now where i should put this `FOO` policy?  should i add in  `tunnel-group 74.201.x.x general-attributes` with `default-group-policy`?  could you please add example config or command in your answer would be helpful

Comment: @Satish You've got it right. You add it to your tunnel-group like you just said.  I edited my answer anyway, to be clear.

Comment: Got it, now anyway i can test this is working or any show command?  also i have set `sla monitor` yesterday but that didn't work my tunnel was down this morning, also i have noticed when i ping from ASA to remote site it doesn't ping and not generating interesting traffic but when i ping from any LAN traffic it generate interesting traffic and bring tunnel up.. i need to find out why ping from `asa` doesn't trigger tunnel.

Comment: does `sla` support source interface? i found when i `ping x.x.x.x` to trigger tunnel it use `outside` interface instead of `inside`, i want to tell sla use inside interface

Comment: @Satish Part of configuring an SLA is defining the target, which can't be completed without specifying which interface to use to reach said target.  I'll edit my answer again to show you.

Comment: I have configure sla with source interface, now when i check `show sla monitor operational-state`  output i am seeing `Latest operation return code: Timeout`  This means my ping isn't working.. but when i do `ping inside 10.10.10.1` it works, look like `sla` doesn't using correct interface to reachout

Comment: @Satish SLAs need to be set to use your "outside" interface when being used in conjunction with a tunnel, since that's the only way to reach the destination.

Answer (score 0):

https://community.cisco.com/t5/vpn/keep-a-vpn-tunnel-on-asa/m-p/3789508

you will find the ASA embedded event manager quite useful